# Multiple text box search ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

How would I go about querying my localDB taking values from multiple textboxes? I am using Entity Framework.

This is my view:

```
@*//implementing search options*@
<br />
<br />
<b> Search Option: </b>
<br />
<br />
<text> Last Name: </text> @Html.TextBox("lname")
<br />
<text> Alt Name: </text> @Html.TextBox("altname")
<br />
<text> First Name: </text> @Html.TextBox("fname")
<br />
<br />
<text> Year of Event: </text> @Html.TextBox("year")
<br />
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Search", 
"Home")'"> </button>
```

As you can see, I am calling the "Search" method from my Home controller. My question is should I pass all the textbox values to the method, and then construct the query for the DB there? Or should I construct the query first, and then pass just the query to the "Search" method? I want to make sure I am using the best practices.

```
        public ActionResult Search(string queryString)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

This is my search Action method, currently I have it setup where I would like to just pass the query string into it, but if I need to edit that, and construct the whole query in the actual method itself, I can go ahead and make that change.

Thanks,

HR

Comment: I would build a viewmodel, pass that to your Search GET, then add a form and POST it back. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Answer (score 1):

I would create a view model with the exacted named entries as you are building in your view. I would also change your variable names and make them camel-case.

```
public class SearchParams {
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public string AltName { get; set; }
     public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

From there you can change your view to use the model in your Razor elements. So `@Html.TextBox("lname")` becomes `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)`. This way your input form is tightly bound to your view model. You will also need to wrap the inputs and submit button (your form) inside a razor form, with something like this: `@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home"))`

From there you must modify your controller. `public ActionResult Search(string queryString)` now becomes `public ActionResult Search(searchParams searchParam)` and your model data is accessible as searchParams.LastName.

```
public ActionResult Search(searchParams searchParam) {
   var lastName = searchParam.LastName;
}
```

From here I would continue to modify your view to leverage more MVC features.

- You can change `<text> Last Name: </text>` to be `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LastName)` if you add a DisplayName meta attribute on your view model.
- Your submit button can be as simple as `<button type="submit">Save</button>`

Your finaly models should look something like this:

```
public class SearchParams {
     [DisplayName("First Name")]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     [DisplayName("Last Name")]
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     [DisplayName("Alt Name")]
     public string AltName { get; set; }

     [DisplayName("Year")]
     public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

Then a rough look at the view would be:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home")) 
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AltName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AltName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Year)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Year)

    <button type="submit">Search</button>
}
```

You will need to add some HTML / CSS to clean it up, but that is the MVC part of the solution.

*My recommendation for you is to learn about Razor controls and how to use them. They will make all of this very simple.*

Comment: Don't forget, you need to change the code to use an actual form, and change the button to submit.  Or, use some kind of javascript to submit it.

Comment: Thank you @eric, I will try to implement as you have displayed above. If anything I believe this will give me a solid starting foundation being able to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Thanks Erick I did not see he had not implemented the Html.BeginForm

Comment: @EricPackwood Do you have any opinions on using a JsonResult instead of an ActionResult in my controller?

Comment: @raha I would only do this if you want to use the data in your result as pure JavaScript. Othersie you can display your result data again using Razor controls. So, if you want to keep it tight and MVC, then use Razor controls, but if you want to use a more JavaScript approach with Angular/React/Knockout, then JSON can be used. If you want to mix the 2, you can put in razor code to convert your model into a JSON object. Remember you can mix JavaScript and your Model with Razor inside the view.

Comment: @EricPackwood My end goal of this project is to use this search page(view) create a query, then I want to run the query on 3 different DB tables. All with different data and fields, but all containing the same basic fields (fname, lname, etc.) After querying the three separate tables, I want to return the results all into one View, using Jquery UI tabs I will separate the results into tabs. I had a friend tell me I should use JSON / Ajax to accomplish this, which is why I asked your opinion on the matter. Thanks